# history pushState and scroll position

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, pushstate, html5-history

I am trying to retrieve the scroll position when a user navigates back in the browser history using HTML5 popstate handler.

Here is what I have:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $(window).on('popstate', PopStateHandler);

    $('#link').click(function (e) {

        var stateData = {
            path: window.location.href,
            scrollTop: $(window).scrollTop()
        };
        window.history.pushState(stateData, 'title', 'page2.html');
        e.preventDefault();

    });

});

function PopStateHandler(e) {
    alert('pop state fired');
    var stateData = e.originalEvent.state;
    if (stateData) {
        //Get values:
        alert('path: ' + stateData.path);
        alert('scrollTop: ' + stateData.scrollTop);
    }
}


<a id="link" href="page2.html"></a>
```

When I navigate back, I am unable to retrieve the values of the stateData.

I presume this is because the popstate is retrieving the values of the initial page load and not the state I pushed to the history when the hyperlink was clicked.

How could I go about getting the scroll position on navigating back?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I managed to solve this one myself:

We must overwrite the current page on the history stack before navigating to the new page.

This allows us to store the scroll position and then pop it off the stack when we navigate back:

```
    $('#link').click(function (e) {

        //overwrite current entry in history to store the scroll position:
        stateData = {
            path: window.location.href,
            scrollTop: $(window).scrollTop()
        };
        window.history.replaceState(stateData, 'title', 'page2.html');

        //load new page:
        stateData = {
            path: window.location.href,
            scrollTop: 0
        };
        window.history.pushState(stateData, 'title', 'page2.html');
        e.preventDefault();

    });
```

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't seem like you can update the current state before a popstate event occurs. For now I'm ignoring this hitch, just like how soundcloud.com has.

Answer (score 2):

Find a way to make this more dynamic with jQuery, hope this can help :

```
$(".lienDetail a").on('click',function(){
    history.pushState({scrollTop:document.body.scrollTop},document.title,document.location.pathname);
}
```

here the solution without jQuery :

```
function pushHistory(e){
    e = e || window.event;
    var target;
    target = e.target || e.srcElement;
    if (target.className.match(/\blienDetail\b/)){
        history.pushState({scrollTop:document.body.scrollTop},document.title,document.location.pathname);
    }
}

if (document.body.addEventListener)
{
        document.body.addEventListener('click',pushHistory,false);
}
else
{
    document.body.attachEvent('onclick',pushHistory);
}
```

This will push history state for each click on link with  lienDetail class for list of results for example