# restore scroll position via history push/replace state

Tags: reactjs, routes, navigation, history

i have a list where i can access detail views of my list items.
in my detail views i can navigate betweeen my list items.

i would like to have a back button on the detail view which brings me to my list view no matter how often i navigated in my detail views.

currently i tried this:
i pass a url: string to my navigation component.
thats the url to my list.

then i want to change my state when i click the back button:

```
 const onClickBack = () => {
        const stateData = {
            path: window.location.href,
            scrollTop: 300
        }
        window.history.replaceState(stateData, "", backURL)


        const stateData2 = {
            path: window.location.href,
            scrollTop: 300
        }

        window.history.pushState(stateData2, "", backURL)

        window.history.back()
    }
```

i copied this code from [history pushState and scroll position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16731271/history-pushstate-and-scroll-position)

no matter how often i navigated, i can go back to my list now. but how can i restore the whole state, e.g. the scroll position?

do i have to pass the whole state object?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you want to manually restore the scroll position. If this is the case, then you should tell the history API about your intention.

```
if ('scrollRestoration' in history) {
  // Back off, browser, I got this...
  history.scrollRestoration = 'manual';
}
```

This way, the scroll position of the previous URL will remain as well.

docs: https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/09/history-api-scroll-restoration